# List<> Filling Error (Void)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, arraylist

For my work I need to create a page that gets all the data for that page from a database using the kellerman framework.

The problem is that I can't seem to create a certain part.

```
List<TextBlockDataObject> t = new List<TextBlockDataObject>();
t.Add(new TextBlockDataObject() { Translations = (List<content new List<ContentTranslationDataObject>().Add(new ContentTranslationDataObject() { LangueageCode = "Eng", TextValue = "TestingText" } ) });
```

> Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to

When I try to build the object trough a other way I get other errors related to bad object creation.

### Other Code I used for testing

```
var tmpTextDataObjs = new List<TextBlockDataObject>();
tmpTextDataObjs.Add(new TextBlockDataObject());


List<ContentTranslationDataObject> ContentTransDataObject = new List<ContentTranslationDataObject>();

ContentTransDataObject.Add(new ContentTranslationDataObject() { LangueageCode = "Eng", TextValue = "this is a test.." });

tmpTextDataObjs[0].Translations = ContentTransDataObject.ToArray();

tmpPage.TextBlockDataObjects = tmpTextDataObjs.ToArray();

var titleObj = new List<ContentTranslationDataObject>();

titleObj.Add(new ContentTranslationDataObject(){LangueageCode = "Eng", TextValue = "444"});

tmpPage.TitleTranslations = titleObj.ToArray();
```

the code above works for a few elements but in the end the page doesn't get created.

Hope anyone can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `Add()` on a newly created List object that you are trying to add to another List property. `Add()` returns `void`, not the new list.

Split up your declarations and assignments and you should be fine. Also, I recommend using the `var` keyword to lessen code duplication/boilerplate as well as using IList instead of List (always use a more generic type/interface when possible).

If you want to initialize the objects inline you can use the anonymous array initializer syntax.

```
IList<myType> myList = new[] { new myType(), new myType() };
```

Comment: Thanks i can compile now